# Are there any types of cancer that cause neurons to divide?

Tags: neuroscience, brain, cancer, neurology

After birth neurons generally do not divide. But is there any specific type of rare cancer or tumour where neurons divide? And if there is such a cancer, then how is it possible for a neuron to regain the division power?

Comment: Related: http://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/10809/extremely-rare-occurence-of-heart-cancer

Comment: You mean brain tumors? Those are actually not that rare...

Comment: @nico I think brain tumours are caused by uncontrolled division of glia that surrounds the neurons not of neurons themselves.

Comment: @biogirl: actually you are right, most brain tumours are glial. However, gangliocytomas have neuronal components and neurocytomas are strictly neuronal, although rare.

Comment: @nico Then I think the author is specifically asking about neurocytomas. Hmmm Interesting !

Comment: @nico pinging you cause you seem to be our resident neuro person. Surely it's not true that neurons don't divide after birth! They don't divide after a certain age but that's a good few years after birth isn't it? I thought it was after adolescence.

Comment: @terdon: new neurons can be born in the adult brain. The phenomenon is less important (in terms of numbers) compared to other cell types, but still it exists. Adult neurogenesis has been reported in pretty much all mammals (see for instance: http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/16022595 ). To be honest, I do not know until what age this happens. Surely in the mouse adult neurogenesis is seen also even well after adolescence.

Answer (score 7):

I think that most mature cells do not divide in all tissues. If an organism needs to repair tissues, it uses tissue cell precursors -- stem cells.

In case of neurons, these are [neuroblasts](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neuroblast). Neuroblasts can divide and can repair brains under some circumstances (I don't know under which).

There is a cancer grown from neuroblasts, called [neuroblastoma](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neuroblastoma).

I think it is very improbable to have tumor from neurons, because division genes are turned off in mature cells. Can't state it is not occurring in practice.